# Расширение модели проведениями behaviors

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Модель Player хранит имя игрока, его силу. Проект на стадии разработке, дабы облегчить модель я вынес функционал в отдельный классы поведения. Поведения так-же будут на уровень, опыт, ресурсы и т.п. Всё это собирается вместе в модели и непосредственно работает как единое целое. Хотелось бы узнать, правильно я использую принцип отделения функционала в yii2?

Модель Player.php

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use yii\base\Model;
use app\components\Damage;
class Player extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
 * Player model
 *
 * @property int $id 
 * @property string $name
 * @property in $damage
 **/
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'players';
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [

            'damage' => [
                'class' => Damage::className(),
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Поведение Damage.php

```
class Damage extends Behavior
{
    /**
 * Damage behavior
 * Поведение расширяет модели, работающие с параметром damage
 **/

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function getDamage()
    {
        return $this->owner->damage + 5 * 2;
    }

    public function getDamageMin()
    {
        return !is_null($this->owner->damage) ? round($this->owner->damage * 0.8) : null;
    }

    public function getDamageMax()
    {
        return !is_null($this->owner->damage) ? round($this->owner->damage * 1.3) : null;
    }

}
```

Использование:

```
$player = \app\models\Player::findOne(1);
$player->getBehavior('damage')->damage
```

Comment: "Если у вас в модели ничего нет, то зачем вам модель?" Поведение - очень непонятная штука, внедренная в Yii, которая не несет в себе никакого смысла; предполагается, что это горизонтальное наследование, но на практике горизонтальное наследование никогда не нужно. Вы, скорее всего, ищете отделение бизнес-логики от данных, и в этом случае модель вообще никак не должна знать о бизнес-логике.

Comment: @Etki В таком случае Разбить на несколько моделей? Модель Player будет работать только с таблице players, Модель UnitPlayer будет включать бизнес логику? Я хочу вынести некоторые части модели Player, в случае с несколькими моделями, в модель UnitPlayer в компонент, потому-что, к примеру Damage будет у игрока, босса, моба и т.п. Или стоит вынести общее в родительскую модель Unit и от нее уже наследоваться?

Comment: Бизнес-логика не имеет ничего общего с наследованием. Вам нужны сервисы, которые будут оперировать моделями, не имеющими в себе бизнес-логики. С точки зрения игры, у вас не три модели - игрок, NPC, босс - а три вида персонажа, которые ничем кардинальным в бою друг от друга не отличаются.

Comment: @Etki, да, всё верно, три вида живых сущностей. Как я понимаю, нужно расширять модель Player не путем наследования, а подключением ёё в конструкторе класса расширяющего интерфейса. Будет ActiveRecord модель Player для работы с таблицей и будет некий интерфейс-прослойка для работы с Player, например в этой модели будут поведения и логика, если, к примеру у игрока 0 ХП, то считать его мёртвым, работать с уровнем игрока, опытом игрока, подключая соответствующий модели. Правильно я рассуждаю?